# C# SMTP Send Email Timeout

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have searched and read many solutions on SE for this but to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("david@me.com","david@me.com");
            mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            mailMessage.Body = "message";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.office365.com", 587);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user","pass");
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
            smtpClient.Timeout = 20000;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

It times out with the message - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The operation has timed out.'

Any help please!

I have also tried a few IP addresses, 25, 465 and 587.

If I enter the smtp address into my browser on the same computer it brings up the login page and I can login with the credentials.

Edit:  I'm running this as a console app if that makes any difference.

Comment: The code looks fine for sending through Office 365 to me (I use something almost identical). It's possible something blocks just your application such as firewall or other network configuration but it's hard to say.

Comment: Do you have any proxy?

Comment: Some guides give other SMTP addresses such as `smtp.office365.com`, have you tried this?

Comment: AFAIK it's "outlook" for POP3 and IMAP and simply "smtp" for SMTP, not "smtp.outlook". At least that is what the german telekom says.

Comment: Tried smtp.office365.com but no difference, thanks for the suggestion though!